# Грамматика слова "спустя"

Tags: грамматика

"За тридцать лет спустя после аварии [ничего не изменилось]" - если это ошибка, то какая?

UPD
Посмотрел в словарях - еще не легче.

У Лопатина "спустя" - только предлог, А у Кузнецова - наречие, но тоже только в сочетании с "немного". А как же "Двадцать лет спустя"?

Answer (score 3):

Да, это речевая ошибка. Возможный вариант:

> За тридцать лет, прошедшие после аварии, ничего не изменилось.

При правильном употреблении выражение "тридцать лет спустя" отсылает к *ранее* названному или подразумеваемому событию (как в заголовке романа "Двадцать лет спустя"), от которого отсчитываются 30 лет и которое после этого больше не указывается (здесь же сказано об аварии). "Спустя" указывает не на период ("за" в исходном примере этому противоречит), а на момент во времени, соответствующий концу срока (к этому моменту привязывают другое событие или действие); вариант корректного употребления:

> В конце прошлого века произошла такая-то катастрофа.  Тридцать лет
>   спустя было доказано, что её можно было предотвратить.

Comment: Да ну что вы фантазируете? 30 лет Чернобылю на календаре, целиком фраза звучала так: "За тридцать лет спустя после аварии отношение к радиации не изменилось". (Или наоборот изменилось. ))) Это живая речь, там другой раз отрицательная частица превращается в усилительную. )))

Comment: Я вообще не имел в виду Чернобыль,  но оживлять речь ошибками - приём интересный :)

Answer (score 1):

Предложение перегружено конфликтующими привязками ко времени. Их хватит на три отдельных фразы.

> После аварии жители покинули город. За тридцать лет в нём ничего не
>   изменилось. Спустя тридцать лет он выглядит, как будто прохожие
>   только-только разошлись по домам.

"После" обозначает время, наступившее следом за событием в прошлом.
"За тридцать лет" задаёт период, в течение которого что-то происходило (или не происходило).
"Спустя тридцать лет" относится к тому, что случилось по окончании этого срока.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка есть. А вот какая... 
Очень хочется признать за грамматическую, но не получается.
Возможно просто смысловая. Предлог "за" означает временной промежуток, а спустя - момент времени.

Посмотрел ответы, могу добавить. Этот конфликт "привязок" - единственный. "За тридцать лет после" - это нормально, значит "за прошедшие 30 лет с того момента". Да и нет другого варианта это сказать, остальное всё - или длинно, или неуклюже.

В отношении "спустя" - да, интересно. А что он идет ***после*** управляемого им слова, академиков, значит, не смущает?! А с другой стороны, не наречие же?!

Comment: А разве то, что вы говорите, про два предлога - не грамматическая ошибка? Мне достаточно для начала признать, грамматическая она или стилистическая. С деталями уже можно разбираться.

Comment: Да может и грамматическая, я-то над этим и думаю, пока не совсем понимаю.